# Firefox sluggish, printing error message

Tags: 12.04, firefox

I am using Firefox via ssh on the following machine:

```
g1> head -1 /etc/motd
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-26-generic x86_64)
g1> firefox -version
Mozilla Firefox 17.0.1
```

When called from an xterm, the following message appears repeatedly. It seems to be printed only when I perform some action, like writing this question. Clicking on something. Otherwise, no message is printed.

```
(firefox:4162): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message
```

While writing this question I received about a dozen such messages.

Is there some way to avoid this (apart from `2> /dev/null`)?

Probably, the following is irrelevant, but who knows:

```
g1> uname -a
Linux g1 3.2.0-26-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 14 17:49:24 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the program `dbus-launch` to get around this issue. So *before* you start Firefox type `export $(dbus-launch)`. Now you can start Firefox. However there might another error message appear. If yes you can work around with `export NSS_USE_SHARED_DB=ENABLED`. Now Firefox should start without error messages or warnings.

Can can put that alltogether in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export $(dbus-launch)
export NSS_USE_SHARED_DB=ENABLED
firefox &
```

If no `dbus-launch` is installed on your system, you should install the package `dbus-x11`. The program is part of this package.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused: `dbus-launch` is what exactly? I see only `dbus-daemon`, `dbus-monitor` and some other commands with that prefix. But there is no dbus-launch. `echo $(dbus-lauch)` gives me: `not found`

Comment: `dbus-launch` is in the package `dbus-x11`. The `echo` command results here in `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-jQBTkG1okn,guid=3ea653d6cc701aabeb9c2f2b0000ea00 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID=22980`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it did remove these errors for me too. But can you explain what these env variables are actually doing?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem but I think it was related to installing other software... I apt-get purged everything, then did an apt-get install dbus-launch, and finally an apt-get autoremove

Comment: What do you mean by "I apt-get purged everything"?